# cannot read properly 'some' of undefined

Tags: node.js, react-native, graphql

I'm not a pro in backend I tried to write a backend server of my app with react-native graphql and I got this error in getPosts resolver.

```
getPosts: async (_, args, { user }) => {
try {
  // await requireAuth(user);
  const p1 = Post.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
  const p2 = FavoritePost.findOne({});
  const [posts, favorites] = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);

  const postsToSend = posts.reduce((arr, post) => {
    const po = post.toJSON();

    if (favorites.posts.some(p => p.equals(post._id))) {
       arr.push({
        ...po,
        isFavorited: true
      });
    } else {
      arr.push({
        ...po,
        isFavorited: false
      })
    }

    return arr;
  }, []);

  return postsToSend;
 } catch (error) {
   throw error;
 }
},
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Could you add the error that your code is throwing for clarity?

Comment: check `favorites.posts` what you are getting